# Tensorflow: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor when feeding through a data generator

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, memory, generator

Below is the data I have artificially created to simulate the actual data I am working with:

```
train_data_list_x = []
train_data_list_y = []

number_of_patients = 20

for i in range(number_of_patients):
    sample_size = int(np.random.randint(low=2000, high=5000, size=1))
    sequence_length = 1024
    feature_size = 3
    
    random_data_x = np.random.rand(sample_size, sequence_length, feature_size).astype(np.float16)
    random_data_y = np.random.rand(sample_size, feature_size).astype(np.float16) 
      
    train_data_list_x.append(random_data_x)
    train_data_list_y.append(random_data_y)
```

The reason I have the data in a list is that it is too large for my memory to concatenate into one - so my approach is to use a data generator as below:

```
def generator(batch_size, from_list_x, from_list_y):

    assert len(from_list_x) == len(from_list_y)
    total_size = len(from_list_x)

    while True: # keras generators should be infinite
        for i in range(0, total_size, batch_size):
            yield np.array(from_list_x[i:i+batch_size]), np.array(from_list_y[i:i+batch_size])
```

I then have my model as below:

```
from keras import Model, layers
from keras.layers import Layer, Dense, LSTM, Dropout, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential


class attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(attention,self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name='attention_weight', shape=(input_shape[-1],1), 
                               initializer='random_normal', trainable=True)
        self.b=self.add_weight(name='attention_bias', shape=(input_shape[1],1), 
                               initializer='zeros', trainable=True)        
        super(attention, self).build(input_shape)
 
    def call(self,x):
        # Alignment scores. Pass them through tanh function
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        # Remove dimension of size 1
        e = K.squeeze(e, axis=-1)   
        # Compute the weights
        alpha = K.softmax(e)
        # Reshape to tensorFlow format
        alpha = K.expand_dims(alpha, axis=-1)
        # Compute the context vector
        context = x * alpha
        context = K.sum(context, axis=1)
        return context

rnn_layer1 = LSTM(units=64, input_shape=(1024, 3), return_sequences=True)
dropout_layer1 = Dropout(rate=0.2)
repeat_vector_layer = RepeatVector(n=1024)
rnn_layer2 = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True)
dropout_layer2 = Dropout(rate=0.2)
time_distributed_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))

model_attention = Sequential()
model_attention.add(rnn_layer1)
model_attention.add(attention())
model_attention.add(dropout_layer1)
model_attention.add(repeat_vector_layer)
model_attention.add(rnn_layer2)
model_attention.add(dropout_layer2)
model_attention.add(time_distributed_layer)

model_attention.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

model_attention.summary()
```

And when I run as follows:

```
hisotry = model_attention.fit_generator(generator(1000, train_data_list_x, train_data_list_y),
                              steps_per_epoch=len(train_data_list)//batch_size,
                              epochs=5
                             )
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Usually this means the components of this array are not all the same shape.  The array is  object dtype, containing arrays (or lists) of differing sizes.  This kind of question is one of the most common `tensorflow` ones.

Comment: Ok so how do I fix this problem? @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

running your code:

```
In [53]: len(train_data_list_x)
Out[53]: 20
In [54]: len(train_data_list_y)
Out[54]: 20
```

creating the generator:

```
In [56]: g = generator(5, train_data_list_x,train_data_list_y)
```

and making one call:

```
In [57]: next(g)
<ipython-input-26-8cfdb554dc4e>:8: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  yield np.array(from_list_x[i:i+batch_size]), np.array(from_list_y[i:i+batch_size])
Out[57]: 
(array([array([[[0.03513, 0.941  , 0.1288 ],
                [0.1338 , 0.04807, 0.855  ],
                [0.598  , 0.1888 , 0.4958 ],
                ...,
                [0.5884 , 0.5137 , 0.8    ],
                [0.3525 , 0.5786 , 0.2993 ],
                [0.4966 , 0.772  , 0.0621 ]],
 .... and so on and on
               ...,
               [0.1343 , 0.2211 , 0.4004 ],
               [0.3455 , 0.752  , 0.4187 ],
               [0.2407 , 0.3555 , 0.616  ]], dtype=float16)], dtype=object))
```

Did you get this `ragged warning`?  If so why did you ignore it.  If not, what version of `numpy` are you running?

As I first guessed, your data is `ragged`, not consistent in shape.

```
In [60]: [y.shape for y in train_data_list_y]
Out[60]: 
[(2339, 3),
 (3760, 3),
 (3681, 3),
 (4210, 3),
 (4862, 3),
 (2832, 3),
 (4972, 3),
 (4912, 3),
 (4018, 3),
 (3960, 3),
 (4194, 3),
 (2598, 3),
 (2294, 3),
 (3477, 3),
 (2254, 3),
 (2881, 3),
 (2241, 3),
 (4425, 3),
 (4319, 3),
 (2877, 3)]
```

Comment: How could this ragged data be reshaped to properly work?

Comment: @hpaulj You are right I did get this warning - I am running numpy version '1.19.5'. How can I mitigate this issue with ragged data?